# Click handler not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some jQuery code that is working fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but is dead as a dodo in IE11. I have read several other posts that are similar, but none seem exactly the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // react to click on Clear Button
    $("#ClearButt").click(function(){
        $("#SearchText").val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="icButton" id="ClearButt">Clear</button>
<input type="text" name="SearchText" id="SearchText" size="40" maxlength="50">
```

I have several click events like this - none of them trigger. Other jQuery code is working OK.
The button is not dynamically generated (I've learnt that lesson).

What peculiarity of IE am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure IE - Script is enabled ?
Then .. open the IE console and see any error is found there on click/trigger

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3pm2prw4/

Comment: try onload instead of ready .

Comment: As Barmar points out, there is no reason this code would not work. Have you checked the console for other errors which are causing this bug?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Script is enabled and other script functions are working.  The JSFiddle works fine ?? There are no console messages.  What else can I check?

Comment: Problem resolved. I had an undeclared variable which Firefox worked around. I realised I had also broken it on the other browsers. Not sure why I didn't see a console error on IE though ??